# How to indent in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the layout below, I would like `version_label` and `installed_label` to be indented 10 spaces.
How is this done in ConstraintLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_app_name"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xl"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version_label"
        android:text="Version: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_app_name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version_number"
        android:text="@string/text_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/last_update_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_app_name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="166dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/installed_label"
        android:text="Installed: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/version_label"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/install_date"
        android:text="@string/text_version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/last_update_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/version_label"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="166dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: 10 spaces? What do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried padding or margins? TextViews are textviews even in ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Sorry 10 px I think is the proper way to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your textviews.

```
android:margin_start="10dp"
```

or

```
android:padding_start="10dp"
```

**Note:**

You should use `dp` over `px` as they are one to one on `mdpi` displays and will scale nicely on devices with higher pixel density.

**Edit:**

In `ConstraintLayout` margins act a little different then other root layouts. Padding is probably your best bet.

Comment: I get an `no resource identifier found for attribute error padding_start`. However, `paddingStart` works. This confuses me in that camel case is not the convention for attributes.

Comment: Sorry, the Android team does that sometimes. I just learned to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of `spaces` is unknown to `ConstraintLayout`. You need to either calculate requied padding/margin and set it from code, or assume that `1 space` = `x dp` and put that padding/margin directly in your layout XML file.

**EDIT**

> Sorry 10 px I think is a better way to say it

No. These are two **completely different** things. Yet, you are most likely willing to set padding on your `TextView`s